# x64 type cast incorrect value

Tags: c++, 64-bit

We are using VS2013. Please find below the sample code, for which we are getting incorrect values for dcp_p variable.
The same sample works fine in x86 platform.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

template <class T>
class MyPointer
{
  public:
     MyPointer(void) : func1_p(0), func2_p(0), func3_p(0),  
          func4_p(0), func5_p(0), func6_p(0), msgFlags_(false) {}

  private:
      bool (T::*func1_p)(void);

       void (T::*func2_p)(void);

       bool (T::*func3_p)(void);

       void (T::*func4_p)(const char *);

       void (T::*func5_p)(const char *);

       void (T::*func6_p)(const char *);

        bool  msgFlags_;
  };


  class dummy{};
  class BaseOne{};
  class BaseTwo{};

  class Derived : public BaseOne, public BaseTwo
  {

   public:
         MyPointer<Derived> dcp;
         void create()
         {

        MyPointer<dummy> *dcp_p = (MyPointer<dummy> *)(&(this->dcp));

       // When we typecast, the dcp_p holds the incorrect values instead of the values assigned by ctor (ie, 0)
      // If multiple inheritance is removed, and have only one base class, dcp_p holds correct value.
     // In x86 platform, the dcp_p values are correct even if multiple inheritance is there.

     printf("%s", "Success");
        }

  };

   int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
   {
       Derived *d = new Derived();
       d->create();
       return 0;
    }
```

Compiler output:  /d1reportAllClassLayout flag

```
  class dummy size(1):
  1>   +---
  1>   +---
  1>  
  1>  
  1>  
  1>  class BaseOne size(1):
  1>   +---
  1>   +---
  1>  
  1>  
  1>  
  1>  class BaseTwo size(1):
  1>   +---
  1>   +---
  1>  
  1>  
  1>  
  1>  class ?$MyPointer@VDerived@@ size(104):
  1>   +---
  1>   0 | func1_p
  1>  16 | func2_p
  1>  32 | func3_p
  1>  48 | func4_p
  1>  64 | func5_p
  1>  80 | func6_p
  1>  96 | msgFlags_
  1>     | <alignment member> (size=7)
  1>   +---

  class Derived size(112):
  1>   +---
  1>   | +--- (base class BaseOne)
  1>   | +---
  1>   | +--- (base class BaseTwo)
  1>   | +---
  1>     | <alignment member> (size=7)
  1>   8 | ?$MyPointer@VDerived@@ dcp
  1>   +---
```

Sample Ouptput for dcp_p:

this = 0x0000000000433D20

dcp_p = 0x0000000000433D28

0x0000000000433D28  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000000433D5F  00 00 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc

Why is the value incorrect when multiple inheritance and x64 bit is used..?

sizeof of all (func_p) are 16.

Also, for MyPointer dcp;  //  all bytes values as zero.

So, the question is, when we typecast why are the values incorrect.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't shown your constructor for `Derived`, so no-one knows how you are initialising `dcp`.

Comment: We did not add explicit ctor for derived. The problem is seen with the sample code provided in VS2013 and x64 platform.

Comment: Why do you want to cast `MyPointer<Derived>*` to `MyPointer<dummy>*`, it's 2 different type, it's Undefined Behavior though

Comment: the question here is why does the cast fail in x64 and multiple inheritance.? and works in x86 with multiple inheritance..

Comment: when MyPointer<Derived> * is converted to void * also, issue is seen.      void *dcp_p = (void *)(&(this->dcp));

Comment: *"the question here is why does the cast fail in x64 and [...] works in x86"* - Because appearing to work is a valid form of undefined behavior. It's still undefined.